# jQuery click working before ng-click

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

This:

```
$("ul")
    .mousedown(function() {
        mouseCode = 1;
    })
```

happens before this:

```
ng-click="setShown(card)"
```

Is there any way to have the ng-click run first? I want to avoid using timeouts if possible.. are there any better ways of making sure these always run in the desired order?

Comment: Is there a reson to not use `ngMouseDown` directive?

Comment: @developer033 I'm passing data in `card` that is a part of `ng-repeat`, so it is convenient to do it that way

Comment: Please provide a plunker or fiddle so that we can help you!